# Android DownloadManager download complete notification opens temp file?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-download-manager

I'm using the following to download a file with `DownloadManager`:

```
        DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://somedomain.com/myfile.jpg);
        String filename = "myDownloadedFile.jpg";

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setTitle(filename);
        request.setDescription("Downloading");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"myAppName/".concat(filename));
        downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

This downloads the file perfectly **and saves it in the correct sub-directory of Downloads**.

However, when I click on the `Download Manager` 'Download Complete' notification (which shows the correct filename and "Download complete") the file that opens is opened from somewhere else and has a numeric filename. According to ES File Manager the file is being opened from `/document/1234` (the number changes for every download) - which is a location I can't even find on my device!

How can I get the notification click to open the file from where it was really saved (i.e. `Downloads/myAppName/myDownloadedFile.jpg`)?

---

To explain further for @blackapp:

If I click on the notification the correct downloaded image opens in any app I choose (I am using ES Image Browser, for example), but if I look at the file properties (in ES Image Browser) it say that the file location is `/document/1234`.

The file IS, however, correctly being saved in `Downloads\myAppName\myDownloadedFile.jpg` by the code above - I have confirmed this by browsing to the `Downloads/myAppName/` folder on my device.

The notification shows the downloaded filename `myDownLoadedFile.jpg` correctly, but when I click the notification that is not the name of the file that opens.

Comment: No not from /document/1234 but from content://<provider>/document/1234.

Comment: I want the notification to open the file from `Downloads/myAppName/myDownloadedFile.jpg`.

Comment: You did not react on what i told you about what you call location. Why not??? Which app shows the wrong file? And how should ES Explorer know that file? Please tell the whole story.

Comment: I've added more explanation to the end of the question as comments are too short. Your comment on its own did not make any sense to me as it only seemed to explain that the location of the opened file in ES Image Browser was not complete. That didn't explain how to get the notification click to open the file from the Downloads subdir.

Comment: `(in ES Image Browser) it say that the file location is /document/1234.` Then you should read further as i already told you that that is no location but part of a content:// scheme. You better dont use this bad es explorer image browser as its only rubbish and nonsense that you learn from it. Take a better app.

Comment: @blackapps Really? Is that the problem? Bogus information from ES Image Browser? That's odd, because Google Photos app tells me exactly the same thing.... So what you are saying is that when I click the notification it IS opening it from the `Downloads/myAppName` folder and it is opening the `myDownloadedFile.jpg` file correctly, not some interim downloaded file before it was moved/copied to the final destination?

Comment: Indeed. It opens the right file served by a content provider in use by downloadmanager. As soon a a content provider serves a file from say Download directory then in the used content scheme uri that Download directory does not have to be visible or named. You could all test your self if you used FileProvider to serve your file.

Comment: So a provider can use .../12345 for a file from DCIM and ../12346 for a file from Pictures. It obscures origin and names of files if it wants.